# How to apply whitelist prune filter to only some subfields

Tags: logstash

I'm using logstash to parse a JSON, and I want to remove some of the fields before I pass it off to elasticsearch.

my json is structured like this:

```
{  
    "several fields to keep": "data",  
    "response": {  
        "fields to keep": "data",
        "json": {  
            "discard all non-whitelisted fields in here": "data"  
        },  
    "request": {  
        "fields to keep": "data",
        "json": {  
            "discard all non-whitelisted fields in here": "data"  
         },  
         "args": {  
             "discard the entire args field": "unsafe user data"
         }
     }
}
```

The input has the json wrapped in other text, so I'm using the `tcp` input plugin, without a codec. I then use `grok` to put the json into a field called `data` and then use

```
json {  
    source => "data"  
    target => "data"  
}
```

Removing `[data][request][args]` is easy (I can just use `remove_field` in the `prune` filter), but I'm having trouble coming up with a way to apply the whitelists to `[data][response][json]` and `[data][request][json]` without having to list all the other field names. I don't want any other fields removed.

If I have to change the structure of the output, that's fine. The next system downstream hasn't been configured yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate your question with some more JSON code examples and scenario. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had an idea for how to work around this. If I take the subfields I want to keep in `[data][response][json]` and move them to somewhere else (I think the `mutate` filter can do that), I can then drop the entire `[data][response][json]` field. It's not what I originally had in mind, but it should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's probably the best you can do unless you want to use the [ruby filter](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/ruby).